# capture process ID of nohup in crontab

Tags: cron, nohup

How can I capture and store the process ID of a `nohup` command that run in crontab?

this is my cron

```
35 * * * * cd /home/ubuntu/aws/&&nohup python3 upload_s3.py >> output_upload_occ.txt
```

Ideally, I want to know what is process ID given and store it for later analysis

i.e `nohup python3 upload_s3.py >> output_upload_occ.txt` will give
`[1] 68585` I want to store this PID into log file.

Comment: Don't treat the `crontab` entry like a `bash` shell. It's not. Use the `crontab` entry to call a `bash` (or whatever) script.

Comment: If it's forking into the background (as suggested by the job control message `[1] 68585`) then you should be able to obtain the PID via shell special parameter `$!` (I believe this should work directly from the crontab, even though cron uses /bin/sh by default).